# CSS Hover effect within Modal popup issue

Tags: css, modal-dialog, css-position, modalpopupextender

i have created a web page with a modal popup control.
Within this control i dynamically build a html  to display data.
Within some of the tables  tags i have the following:

```
<td>
<a href="#"><span>S</span><span class="pop">description</span></a>
</td>
```

i want to create a popup effect when hovering over the  tag.
My CSS is:

```
a .pop {
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: solid 2px #000000;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover .pop {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

This works perfectly when i use the control within a standard HTML page.
It appears to work within the modal popup control, until i need to scroll down the modal control when the table data is larger that the modal window.

The hover effect then appears to not be working.  I think this is because im using the "position":"absolute" for the ".pop" class, and the hover effect is working, but its position is no longer relative to the  tag because I have scrolled through the page.

I am not able to get round this and its killing me.  Do i need to dynamically reposition the control using a "mouseover" event, or can this be achieved via CSS, and I’m just missing something / being a novice.

Karl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
a { display:block; position:relative }
```

This will make the span.pop be positioned relativily to the a tag it is in.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/R4Erw/

Comment: That worked great. Many thanks. One final question:  when i hover over the field, the popup displayed is really small in width, almost wrapping after every word.  Is it inheriting its width from the table cell <td>?
i know i can set the width / min-width of the popup, but can i do something so it intelligently knows how wide it would need to be, because in some instances I need only enough space for 1 character, and others I need lots of space for descriptions.